# Trouble dynamically routing paths in React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, dynamic-routing

I have been trying to dynamically route the component to the url. Have made use of userParam() hook. But it is not rendering.

[image: The error message is as per following.]

The data is available in the following file called servicesData.js file

```
let serviceData = [
    {
        "name": "Lawn Mowing",
        "price": 30,
        "_id": "1",
        "description": "Have a carpet-like lawn without any work."
    },
    {
        "name": "Leaf Raking",
        "price": 50,
        "_id": "2",
        "description": "Remove those pesky dead tree parts from your property."
    },
    {
        "name": "Weeding",
        "price": 50,
        "_id": "3",
        "description": "Don't let the invaders ruin your yard."
    },
    {
        "name": "Sprinkler repair",
        "price": 100,
        "_id": "4",
        "description": "Keep your irrigation system top-notch."
    }
]

 export default serviceData
```

The index.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
// import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom"
import ServicesApp from "./ServicesApp.js"
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <ServicesApp />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

The ServiceApp.js file.

```
import React from "react"
import Home from "./components/Home"
import ServicesList from "./pages/services/servicesList"
import ServiceDetail from "./pages/services/serviceDetail"
import HeaderService from "./components/HeaderService";
import {Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom"

function ServicesApp() {
    return (
        <div>
            <HeaderService />

            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/services" >
                    <ServicesList />
                </Route>
                <Route  path="/services/:serviceId" >
                    <ServiceDetail />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ServicesApp
```

The servicesList.js file.

```
import React from "react"
import serviceData from "./servicesData"
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
function ServicesList() {
    const services = serviceData.map(service =>(
        <h3 key={service._id}><Link to={`/services/${service._id}`}>{service.name}</Link> - ${service.price}</h3>
    ))
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Services List Page</h1>
            {services}
        </div>
    )
}
export default ServicesList
```

The ServiceDetail file is.

```
import React from "react"
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom"
import servicesData from "./servicesData"

function ServiceDetail(props) {
    const {serviceId} = useParams()
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
    const thisService = servicesData.find(service => service._id === serviceId)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Service Detail Page</h1>
            <h3>{thisService.name} - ${thisService.price}</h3>
            <p>{thisService.description}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ServiceDetail
```

The HeaderService file.

```
import React from "react"
import {Link} from "react-router-dom"

function HeaderService() {
    return (
        <header>
            <ul>
                <li><Link exact to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link exact to="/services">Services</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
    )
}

export default HeaderService
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail other than it's not working? Are there any error messages? Can you provide a working, running codesandbox that reproduces the issue? If you correctly console log the `serviceId` in an `useEffect` in `ServiceDetail` does it log correctly?

Comment: Well, `const {serviceId} = useParams()` certainly appears to be a valid react hook usage, called from body of a functional component. What are the React and ReactDOM versions installed? Greater than v16.8.4 and matching?

Comment: @DrewReese I have edited the ServiceDetail file. The error message is added in the image file, that error is produced on the nested dynamic route.

Comment: react-dom: 17.0.1 is the version

Comment: And the React version? I'm unable to reproduce the issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/trouble-dynamically-routing-paths-in-react-router-96qcd

Comment: @DrewReese hey I just woke up today and it started working. I guess there was some issue with the dependency.

Comment: If the issue now unreproducible for you as well then I'm voting to close. Cheers.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes Please vote to close this issue